# create a new table from a select?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a new table from a select but it isn't working.
Here is my syntax

```
select *
into newtable
from oldtable
where oldtable.number=2
```

Then, when I try to use it

```
select * from newtable
```

it tells me that newtable is an invalid object.

Comment: Did you have SET FMTONLY ON somewhere in the batch? See here, it should work as-is: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/933f3/1/0. Have you ***actually*** run it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code other than you need to drop `newTable` before you run it again

Comment: No SET FMTONLY ON anywhere. what I gave you is literally all that I have in the code.

Comment: Can you run the SQL provided by @RichardTheKiwi on your SQL Server?

Comment: I don't believe your tables are named newtable, oldtable. Are you 100% certain you didn't change the name of "newtable" between the two snippets of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you in the right database, and not in the master?

Try this:

```
USE [your database name]
GO

SELECT *
INTO newtable
FROM oldtable
WHERE [number] = 2
```

If newtable has a red underline, you can still select from it.  The underline just means that the table name is not cached.  You can rebuild IntelliSense by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+R and the underline will disappear.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into newtable
select *
from oldtable
where oldtable.number=2
```